# How to pass a json string as parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have received a json string like this:

The Api response as following list:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1018491557",
        "results": "{\"combo\":\"3,4,13,14\"}",
        "time": "2020-07-13T16:11:03.082Z",
        "modifiedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "status": "SUCCESS"
    },...
]
```

Then I mockup html like this and I need to open the modal to show single details:

```
var res = 
'<a href="#" onclick="openDetails(\''+value.id+'\', \''+value.results+'\', \''+value.time+'\', \''+value.modifiedTime+'\')">';
$(".list").append(res);
```

But I just cant get the right format of **RESULTS** to display.

```
function openDetails($id, $res, $time, $modTime){
    $("#DetailsModal").remove();
    var modal =
        '<div id="DetailsModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">'+
            '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">'+
                '<div class="modal-content">'+
                    '<div class="modal-header">'+
                        '<h5 class="modal-title">Details</h5>'+
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">'+
                        '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+
                    '</button>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="modal-body">'+
                        '<p>ID: '+$id+'</p>'+
                        '<p>Sesults: '+$res+'</p>'+
                        '<p>Time: '+$time+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
    $("body").append(modal);
    $("#DetailsModal").modal({
        backdrop:"static",
        keyboard:false,
        show:true
    });
}
```

Anyone can point me out here?  Thanks

**solved!**
Okay~ it turns out no need to quote the string again. problem solved by replacing the double quotes to single.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDetails(\''+value.id+'\', '+value.results.replace(/"/g, "'")+', \''+value.time+'\', \''+value.modifiedTime+'\')">
```

Comment: Attach the event handler from code or otherwise delegate to a function without trying to supply a value via the HTML markup .. it makes life easier. Then it’s just a matter of scoping (the variable needs to be accessible from the handler) and timing (the variable should not be accessed prior to any async operation that fetches it is complete).

Comment: Its just simply display to another modal to show the details, nothing more.

Comment: @user2864740 can you paste a sample code without via the html?

Comment: You need to use 
JSON.stringify

Comment: @Mrfrog Where to? right before it pass to the function? cause that wont work~

Comment: try JSON.stringify(res), ex: console.log(JSON.stringify(res))

Comment: @Mrfrog but the problem is I can NOT pass it there~

Comment: The most trivial change is using: onclick=“return openDetails(event)” and making the openDetails function access some globally accessible object, whatever that may be. This makes it clear the value is acessed from an object with such a scope. The HTML has already been parsed, so no amount of adding quotes is necessary in any case. The handler will need to wait until the JSON (really variable) has been properly assigned.

Comment: Then you need to post here your function code and how are you calling it?

Comment: posting more relevant codes would help a lot

Comment: @user2864740 I think I got what you mean, will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I will post the rest of code but there is not much left seriously.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks man it is no need to adding any quotes at all, and also I have replace the double quotes to single one inside the string, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your code is, but if you get a json string you have to use `JSON.parse()` to transform it into a JavaScript object.

```
var result = JSON.parse('{"combo":"3,4,13,14"}');
...
<a href="#" onclick="openDetails(result)">
```